# How can I indicate to a test that wait for a retrofit response?

Tags: android, junit, retrofit2, robolectric

Hello I am trying develop a unit test, for getting data from an api for doing this I have the following:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RouteTest {
    LoginRepository profileRepository = new LoginRepository(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    MapRepository mapRepository = new MapRepository(RuntimeEnvironment.application);

    private ActivityController<LoginActivity> loginController;
    private ActivityController<MapActivity> mapController;

    private LoginActivity loginActivity;
    private MapActivity mapActivity;

    private void createActivitiesWithIntents() {
        loginActivity = loginController.create().start().get();
        mapActivity = mapController.create().start().get();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        loginController = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class);
        mapController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MapActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalculateRoute() {
        System.out.println("Start Test");

        MutableLiveData<ApiResponseWithDataList<LoginData>> loginData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        MutableLiveData<ApiResponseWithData<ItineraryResponseData>> itineraryData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        profileRepository.login(loginData, EMAIL, PASS);
        createActivitiesWithIntents();

        loginData.observe(loginActivity, (@Nullable ApiResponseWithDataList<LoginData> loginResponse) -> {
            System.out.println("Do login for get Access Token");

            String accessToekn = loginResponse.getData().getAccessToken();
            ItineraryBody itineraryBody = new ItineraryBody();

            mapRepository.calculateRoute(itineraryData, accessToekn, itineraryBody);
        });

        itineraryData.observe(mapActivity, (@Nullable ApiResponseWithData<ItineraryResponseData> itineraryResponse) -> {
            System.out.println("Getting route");

            System.out.println("Finish Test");
        });
    }
}
```

And when execute this test, I get the next output

> Start Test
>
> Do login for get Access Token

Then the test never wait for itineraryData.observe, any idea that how can do for the test wait to response in itineraryData?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will answer your question, but I assume root cause of your problem is that **test runner** and **itineraryData.observe()** work on different threads.

Test runner thread knows nothing about the process that was executed in other thread and just ends the test (and there is no console process anymore to show output of your observer thread).

One option is to use [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) library which meant for handling ashynchronous operations.

Second option is to apply some kind of hack to wait for observer thread to finish it's activity before making any assertions. Something like:

```
    try {
      final Optional<Thread> observerThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(it -> it.getName().startsWith(YOUR_OBSERVER_THREAD_PREFIX))
          .filter(it -> it.getState().equals(RUNNABLE))
          .findFirst();

      //need to figure out how long will be enough for you 
      final int maxThreadSleep = 30; 

      int i = 0;
      while (observerThread.isPresent()
          && observerThread.get().getState().equals(RUNNABLE) && i < maxThreadSleep) {
        Thread.sleep(2);
        i++;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```